# uninitialized constant Object::Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I am a little new to rails. I am on a mac book pro

I pulled down the poi repo from git but was unable to run anything. 
including

```
rails -s 
rake routes
rake db:migrate
bundle install
rake test
bundle update
```

I am not sure what i'm missing

```
Projects$ git clone https://github.com/tekpub/poi.git poi
Cloning into poi...
remote: Counting objects: 356, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (218/218), done.
remote: Total 356 (delta 91), reused 356 (delta 91)
Receiving objects: 100% (356/356), 199.57 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (91/91), done.
Projects$ cd poi 
poi$ bundle install
/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [Selenium-1.1.14, daemons-1.1.4, eventmachine-0.12.10, js_spec-0.3.3, rack-1.3.5, rake-0.9.2, thin-0.8.1] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'

poi$ rake routes
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::Bundler

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
poi$ 

poi$
```

thanks

=================

## edit

```
poi$ sudo gem install bundler
Password:
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.21
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.21...
poi$ rails routes
/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [Selenium-1.1.14, daemons-1.1.4, eventmachine-0.12.10, js_spec-0.3.3, rack-1.3.5, rake-0.9.2, thin-0.8.1] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
poi$
```

=================

## edit 2

after running `rvmsudo gem install bundler` and still get the same error

```
poi$ rvmsudo gem install bundler
Password:
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.21
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.21...
poi$ rake routes
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rake (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.0.21] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rake:18
poi$
```

===========

## edit 3

I fust ran this and still getting the same issue

```
'sudo gem install rake' 
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2 1 gem installed 
poi$ rake -v 
rake aborted! uninitialized constant Object::Bundler
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't install your gems as root.

From [RVM instructions on gems](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/):

> DO NOT use sudo...
>
> to work with RVM gems. When you do sudo you are running commands as
>   root, another user in another shell and hence all of the setup that
>   RVM has done for you is ignored while the command runs under sudo
>   (such things as `GEM_HOME`, etc...). So to reiterate, as soon as you
>   'sudo' you are running as the root system user which will clear out
>   your environment as well as any files it creates are not able to be
>   modified by your user and will result in strange things happening.
>   (You will start to think that someone has a voodoo doll of your
>   application...)

Just do `gem install [gem]` and see how that works out.

Comment: should i reinstall? http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/

Comment: @eiu If it still doesn't work, I think reinstalling clean and then installing your gems as yourself wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Bundler](http://gembundler.com) gem isn't installed.  Run `gem install bundler` then retry unpacking the Rails app.

Comment: ran sudo gem install bundler the rails and got  `to_specs': Could not find rails. see edit. thanks

Comment: I think it needs to either be `rvmsudo gem install bundler` or just `gem install bundler` for RVM.

Comment: I ran rvmsudo gem install bundler and still get the same error

Comment: just ran  'sudo gem install rake'
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
1 gem installed
poi$ rake -v
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::Bundler

Answer (score 0):

The process should be simply

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

That should be all you need.